# Group adjacent regex matches

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to build a regex that finds the number of syllables in a word with the following conditions:

- Vowels are counted as syllables.
- Two or more consecutive vowels are counted as one syllable
- Ignore 'e' if it is the last letter in a word (don't count it as a syllable)
- Vowels are: 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', and 'y'.

I came up with `[e][aeiou]*(?=[a-z])|[aiouy][aiouy]*(?=[a-z ])`, which you can test [here](https://regex101.com/r/5UoxS7/1). As seen in the test, the word 'they' comes up as two separate matches (e and y are counted separately), which is an issue. How can this be solved?

*Also, if possible, it would be great if there is an explanation to regex solutions*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://regex101.com/r/Lu5GCo/1) is what I ended up with, but I am sure it can be very improved.

```
[aeiouyAEIOUY]+(?!(?<=[eE])[^a-zA-Z]|$)
```

Matches one or more vowels sticky to each other:

```
[aeiouyAEIOUY]+
```

Negated lookahead (what we don't want after our [aeiouyAEIOUY]+):

```
(?!
```

Nested lookahead (what we want to after our negated lookahead):

```
(?<=[eE])
```

Our Nested lookahead followed by a non alphabetic character or the end of the text:

```
[^a-zA-Z]|$)
```

Comment: It works well, thanks for the detailed explanation and solution!